# execute some action after specific shell command => ( Track installed packages )

Tags: linux, shell, install.packages

I just installed a fresh new Linux distro, and I would like to track all the new packages I will install.

Hence, each time I run a `sudo apt-get install packageName`, I Would like to log the specific package to keep track of my configuration.

Then, for new installation, I could write a simple script to choose whether or not I want to install my old packages.

Any of you have a solution ? Maybe something simple is to track the file with all the installed packages ? but I am sure there are many dependencies, and not the basic ones ?

The idea is to watch permanently the shell entry and save the matching string ( package name ) Maybe this is not the best solution.

Thanks in advance for your Help.

Comment: BTW, dpkg already tracks which package installations were requested by the user (as opposed to installed by dependencies) and when. As such, I'm not sure why you'd want to build this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could create script that serves as an alias to your install command which remembers each newly installed package, maybe by appending each entry to a file somewhere. This script could have an option to reinstall packages which if selected, would iterate through each remembered package and prompt if you would like to install it. If you backup that script and the file of installed packages then on your clean machine you would just copy those files and reinstall the desired packages.

Alternatively you could investigate using provisioning tools such as Puppet, Chef, Salt, etc. to provision your system. This might be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of tracking package installation times -- you don't need to; [`apt-get` already records all the metadata you need](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12578/list-packages-by-installation-date%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B) (see in particular `/var/log/apt/history.log`). As such, you really shouldn't have any need to follow the advice below for the use case given.

---

However, as a general answer to the question: Write a wrapper. If `/usr/local/bin` is in front of `/usr/bin` and `/bin` in the PATH that `sudo` creates for root, for instance, then you could put the following in `/usr/local/bin/apt-get`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ^-- using /bin/bash rather than /bin/sh enables printf %q

# Shell-quote the command to unambiguously present arguments even if it contains
# newlines, spaces, etc.
printf -v cmd '%q ' "${0##*/}" "$@"

# Trim the trailing space
cmd=${cmd%" "}

# Log that command
printf '%s\n' "$cmd" >>/var/log/apt-get-commands

# ...and run the real command.
exec /usr/bin/apt-get "$@"
```